# Como ajustar o Form de acordo com o tamanho do PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como eu faço para redimensionar o meu formulário de acordo com o tamanho do componente PictureBox?

Neste caso, as imagens dos captchas podem ter tamanhos diferentes. Então gostaria que meu Form se ajustasse ao tamanho do PictureBox. Por exeplo, se a imagem aumentar de tamanho, o Form deve acompanhar o seu tamanho.

Aqui eu altero o tamanho do PictureBox, mas o Form não redimensiona.

```
public ResolverCaptcha(Bitmap imagemCaptcha, string mensagem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblMensagem.Text = mensagem;
        pctCaptcha.Width = imagemCaptcha.Width;
        pctCaptcha.Height = imagemCaptcha.Height;
        pctCaptcha.Image = imagemCaptcha;
    }
```

Este é o Form:

[image: Form que desejo redimensionar.]

Comment: Seu problema é mudar o tamanho do form ou saber o quanto precisa aumentar? Ou os dois?

Comment: @jbueno Alterar o tamanho do Form! Existe alguma configuração nas propriedades do Form para que ele se ajuste ao tamanho dos componentes ou realmente tenho que modificar o tamanho "na mão"?

Comment: @LucasAlcântara como é carregado a imagem? é tudo na mão!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário alterar o tamanho do `form` "na mão". Ele não vai se redimensionar sozinho.

```
Size = new Size(novaLargura, novaAltura);
```